# Office 365 Unified API - Missing UPN Claim

Tags: azure, office365, office365-apps

My scenario is this.

I need to access user and group data, and create a unified group via my existing SharePoint Provider hosted app. As most of the code runs inside an Azure webjob, I've registered a separate Application against Azure Ad to achieve this.

Now, using the .Net Unified API's I can get to the stage where I have a GraphService Object, but performing any operations results in a Forbidden. Drilling down further shows an Missing UPN Claim error.

Authentication Context Authority = https://login.windows.net/.onmicrosoft.com
Service Root = https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/

Comment: Sorry you are having issues here.  What permission scopes did you configure for your application?

Comment: I think what you are missing is a permission scope, we have a bug right now where these operations require Directory.ReadWrite.All in addition to Groups.ReadWrite.All

Comment: Hi, I've added all perms. My token that is being returned doesn't have any permission levels in it - so something is fairly wrong.

Comment: var serviceRoot = new Uri(ResourceBetaUrl + tenantId); https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/<id>
var authenticationUrl = AzureAdTenantLoginUrl + TenantUPNName; https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant upn name>
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authenticationUrl, false);
_graphClient = new Microsoft.Graph.GraphService(serviceRoot, async () => await GetTokenHelperAsync(authenticationContext));

Comment: private static async Task<string> GetTokenHelperAsync(AuthenticationContext authenticationContext)
{
try
{

ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ClientID, ClientSecret);
var authResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(ResourceUrl, credential);
return authResult.AccessToken;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw;
}
}

Comment: Is the general gist. This gives me an Access token, but it doesn't contain any of the permissions I've applied - leading to a specific error - "Missing UPN claim.". My app is registered correctly I believe - so using the Azure AD App Registrations Client ID and Secret - I'm just hoping I'm going wrong in the process somewhere (perhaps with the Resource/Auth urls? ) and it is actually possible.

Comment: I think this may be the issue -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862712/office-365-unified-api-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object,  the token I receive is much smaller than I would expect (missing perms information). Now, what are the alternatives as because I'm running this in a webjob I can't prompt for auth - this is an app only process.

Comment: Hi GavH, please note that there are two ways to authenticate to AAD. The [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx) and the [Client Credential Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx). It seems like you are using the client credential flow, which means that your token does not have any user context. You want to call [AcquireTokenbyAuthorizationCode](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/29/using-adals-acquiretokenby-authorizationcode-to-call-a-web-api-from-a-web-app/) to get the token you need.

Comment: Appears that it's not possible right now to use the preview unified API in a daemon/job context (App Only) - meaning no Group access via this method. Really frustrating as the intention was to utilize a workflow around this - have to come up with an alternate approach. Any comments MSFT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the unified APIs (including Group APIs) is ONLY supported for now using the delegated (app+user) flows.  We are working on providing app only (client_credential flow) support, and can update this thread when this is available.

HTHs,

Comment: Thanks Dan. An update would be good when it is available. In the meantime I'll look at using the app + user flow.